# jQuery focusout event not working as I want it to

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    <div id="id1">
        <div id="id2">
            <p> some text </p>
        </div>
        <div id="id3">
             <!--some other div elements-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

`#id2` is `contenteditable` when some button on the page is clicked.

My script has the following code:

```
jQuery("#id1").focousout(focousoutFunction);
```

The problem is that if `#id2` loses focus then the `focousoutFunction` is fired.
Is there a way that the `focusout` will only catch the event when the actual element loses focus and not it's inside elements?

Comment: I think you need `blur` instead of `focusout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force javascript to stop propagation.

```
jQuery("#id1 div").focusout(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, **or** any element
>   inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in
>   that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements
>   (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

[Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

the focusout will fire everytime an element inside `#id1` loses focus even though `#id1` did not loses focus itself (although i'm not sure that you can assign focus event to a div element);